# Bad render with vector in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector

I try to use vector in Android Studio (my project is for < 5.0).

For that :

1. I take vector from flaticon.com in the SVG format.
2. After, I go to Android Studio, right click on Drawable, New > Vector Asset
3. I put the SVG image I've downloaded (I change nothing in the parameters)
4. **Next and Save**

After that, I have the xml file in the drawable. I put it on the src of an Imageview...

The problem is : the render of my vector is bad when I put it in a large size.

Why ?

---

EDIT : I found the solution !

I have to click on "**override default size from Material Design**" and change the size.

Comment: What does "bad" mean?  Taach or link an image.  Attach the SVG and/or the VectorDrawable.

Comment: When I said bad, I mean bad quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution !

I have to click on "**override default size from Material Design**" and change the size.